# Delay signal according to normal distribution

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, delay

I am trying to delay a signal by a certain number of samples. This certain number, I would like to generate using a random normal distribution in Matlab. I am using the following for generating the number of samples r = randn(1,1)/sampleTime. This however generates negative numbers too. In order to avoid the negative numbers, I am taking the absolute value of r but I know that this is not the right way, since in this case I would be ignoring the left part of the distribution. Is there a way I can use just positive samples without shifting the mean too much?

Comment: Why are you using a normal distribution if this is not what you actually want? Do you only want to delay the signal by integer multiples of the sampling interval?

Comment: No matter what distribution you use, if it only consists of positive numbers then it is going to have a positive and non-zero mean. You can look at Rician, Rayleigh and Gamma distributions which can be parameterized to so that the mean is small.

Answer (score 1):

Normal distribution regardless of whatever mean and variance you provide, can still produce large positive and negative numbers(albeit with a small probability).

Do you want to specifically use normal distribution, or all you need is a random delay generator? If latter is the case, you can use rand() from MATLAB, also you could use randi if you need integer delays.

Also you could use something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html) to generate uniformly distributed random numbers in a specific range.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a distribution like the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) which is defined only on the positive x-axis unlike the Normal distribution.

MATLAB seems to have [functions](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/gamma-distribution.html) to produce it.